# Random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent have PDF $= \frac{1}{\pi(x^2+1)}$. Show that $aX +bY$ has the same distribution as $(|a| + |b|)X$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent and have the same distribution with PDF $=
\frac{1}{\pi(x^2+1)}$ (such a distribution is called a Cauchy distribution). Show that $aX +bY$ has the same distribution as $(|a| + |b|)X$.

Anybody knows how to do such thing? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think there is a typo. Did you mean $f_{X}(x) = \frac{1}{\pi(x^{2} + 1)}$?

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia yes. I'm sorry. I will edit that in a second. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @ayeayemaung I read about Cauchy distribution on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#cite_note-27) and that's about it. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @ayeayemaung it has something to do with Cauchy distribution being stable (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26801/prove-that-cauchy-distribution-is-stable) I think.

Comment: Show that the characteristic function of $aX + bY$ is the same as that of $(|a| + |b|) X$

Comment: We assume $a,b$ are real?  The question makes sense for $a,b$ complex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$X$ is Cauchy so its (as well as $Y$'s) characteristic function
$$
\varphi_X(s)=\mathbb{E} e^{isX}=e^{-|s|}
$$
(see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution)).
So
$$
\varphi_{aX+bY}(t)=\mathbb{E} e^{itaX+itbY}=\mathbb{E} e^{i(ta)X}\mathbb{E} e^{i(tb)Y}=e^{-|ta|}e^{-|tb|}=e^{-|t|(|a|+|b|)}
$$
which is the ch.f. of a random variable with Cauchy distribution times $|a|+|b|$.